# Expo How to create a development build for android and how to create a .apk file?

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, expo

Ive been reading the documentation and my build seems to succeed, however there is no apk file created. Im not fully sure if im running the right commands. my eas.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 5.7.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "ios": {
        "enterpriseProvisioning": "universal"
      }
    },
    "preview2": {
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleRelease"
      }
    },
    "preview3": {
      "developmentClient": true
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

I am using android on a simulator and ios on device. I run the following command:

`eas build --profile development --platform android`

as the documentation says. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Personnaly I'm using Expo EAS to create apk. I'm using the command:
 `eas build -p android --profile preview`

Comment: and what do you have in your eas file for profile? because I have different profiles in my eas.json and im confused how to run it

Comment: On my side I got this:
```{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 5.4.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `EAS` as well and i find it quite handy. Let me explain the profiles quickly.

**Development**

This type is for developing, it makes it possible to see live reloads, live changes in the application when you change it. You can even pass env. variables if needed.

> eas build --profile development --platform android

**OR**

To make a local build so the Expo Application Service is `skipped`

> npx expo run:android

```json
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "env": {
        "API_URL": "X",
      }
```

**Preview**

This creates a `.apk` file that you can install on your device or emulator. Note the the env. variable does not need to be the same as `development`

> eas build --profile preview --platform android

```json
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "env": {
        "API_URL": "Y",
      }
    },
```

**Production**

This creates a `.aab` file which you can upload on to `Google Developer Console`, if you want to set your app on the app store.

> eas build --profile production --platform android

```json
    "production": {
      "env": {
        "API_URL": "X",
      }
    },
```

If you do not need the `env` values, you can safely delete them.

After executing on of the commands in your terminal, a link should appear to `expo.dev` where you can download and install your `development` or `preview` .apk file

Comment: thank you for the explanation. So I managed now to create the apk file and drag it to my android simulator. To create it I changed my eas.json and put "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      } into preview instead of development and I run eas build -p android --profile preview. Now do I also after that need to run eas build -p android --profile development (not to generate the apk file as I already have it)?

Comment: Preview and development builds are totally different and have no overlap. Live changes are only visible in development. When you need a preview build, you execute the `preview command`. When you need a development build, you execute the `development command`.

Comment: so once I run the preview build and generated a apk, then change code, I should run the development build to see the changes?! But I dont need to re run the preview build and generate a new apk file after changes?

Comment: No! You should make a development build firstly. If you change the code and make a button red instead of blue, you can see the change immediately. A Preview build is like a snapshot of the application and will not change if you edit your code. There is no need to make a development or preview build after every code change. You probably only need to make a development build once, unless if you install libraries that need a rebuild

Comment: okay I understand. just so I fully understand: I do not not to create a new apk after changes. correct?

Comment: No, that is why you can make a development build, there live changes can be made and you see the result immediately!

Comment: okay thank you!